# Custom JFileChooser. How to return variable?

Tags: java, swing, variables, custom-component, jfilechooser

I am adding to `JCheckBoxes` to a `JFileChooser` to get let the user chose between some extra options when exporting some data to a text file:

```
  JCheckBox field1 = new JCheckBox("Export people gender");
  JCheckBox field2 = new JCheckBox("Export people age");
  JPanel accessory = new JPanel();
  accessory.setLayout(new BoxLayout(accessory, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
  accessory.add(field1);
  accessory.add(field2);

  JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
  chooser.setAccessory(accessory);
  int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

How do I get the 2 extra checkboxes checked/unchecked value (isSelected() true/false) back to the class from which the chooser is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check their state after the chooser is shown.  I.E. Put the line(s) immediately after:

```
int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Since the chooser is a modal dialog, those code lines will not be executed until the user dismisses it.